# Codeigniter: Connect to SSL Amazon RDS Database

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, amazon-rds

I'm having trouble making a connection to Amazons RDS service from my Codeigniter application.

Settings in database config:

```
$db['default']['ssl_set'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['ssl_key'] = NULL;
$db['default']['ssl_cert'] = NULL;
$db['default']['ssl_ca'] = realpath('./application/third_party/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem');
$db['default']['ssl_capath'] = NULL;
$db['default']['ssl_cipher'] = NULL;
```

However, when I connect. I get the message:

> Unable to select the specified database: Staging 
>   Filename: ...\system\database\DB_driver.php 
>   Line Number: 140

Line 40 is shown here:

```
    // Select the DB... assuming a database name is specified in the config file
    if ($this->database != '')
    {
        if ( ! $this->db_select())
        {
            log_message('error', 'Unable to select database: '.$this->database);

            if ($this->db_debug)
            {
                $this->display_error('db_unable_to_select', $this->database); // LINE 140
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
```

I made the [following changes](https://github.com/mfauveau/codeigniter-reactor/commit/351b4534c36eb1bbde8dfd4157852f137e25b2c7) to get `mysqli` working with SSL:

I'm suprised it connected successfully as its complaining about database selection. Not sure where to go from here though?

I'm using PHP `5.3.8` on a windows machine.

### Update

This is turning more into a bug than a problem with my implementation. If I set the `$db['default']['db_debug']` to `false`. I don't get that problem anymore. However, I get a bunch warnings to do with:

```
Severity: Warning
Message: mysqli_real_escape_string() [function.mysqli-real-escape-string]: invalid object or resource mysqli
Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 346
```

Which means there was an unsuccessful connection to the database over SSL.

### Update 2

I am using XAMPP.

And I am using Codeingiter 2.0.2.

### Update 3

My database config file:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxxxx';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'xxxx';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['port'] = 3306;
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = true;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['ssl_set'] = true; 
$db['default']['ssl_key'] = NULL;
$db['default']['ssl_cert'] = NULL;
$db['default']['ssl_ca'] = realpath('./application/third_party/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem');
$db['default']['ssl_capath'] = NULL;
$db['default']['ssl_cipher'] = NULL;
```

Comment: Can you post your settings for database config?

Comment: Maybe this one can shed you some light...http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/102232/

Comment: I read that post and that's the one I followed. It should be working as it works for others but for me there is something getting in the way, not sure how to debug this!

Comment: Have you turned logging on?If so,can you post the logs to see what is going on?

Comment: On the link I posted, there is the config line mysqli_ssl_set($init, '/etc/ssl/mysql/client-key.pem', '/etc/ssl/mysql/client-cert.pem', '/etc/ssl/mysql/ca-cert.pem', NULL, NULL); which are 3 keys but on your config there is only mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem....is this something you need to look at?

Comment: Because I am using Amazon RDS they only supply one public key and that is all that is required. But I managed to solve the problem! :)

Comment: Good news but how did you solve the problem?Can you post here so someone else can find the solution if having the same problem?

Comment: The solution is basically stormdrain answer and making sure to have the open SSL extension enabled in PHP.

Comment: I thought you enabled it already.Anyway glad that you found an answer...

Comment: Hi @Abs, thanks for the great question and for updating it so thoroughly. I've followed your direction exactly and unfortunately I'm still unable to connect my CI app to my RDS. Is there anything not listed in your question or the answer below that was required for getting your RDS connection to work? You've made it pretty straightforward so I'm really at a loss.

Comment: @Abs, by the way, your code works on my live EC2 server so I'm able to access my db when I go to http://mysite.com. However, it doesn't work in my local environment, i.e., http://localhost (XAMPP localhost on Mac). Is it something about the "Security groups" which are set by default to connect to an "EC2 security group"? Have you gotten it to work on your local environment?

Comment: Not directly related to the answer you marked, but I don't think Codeigniter supports SSL for MySQL connection for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$db['default']['port'] = 3306;
```

Try adding that to db config. `mysql_real_connect()` expects param 6 to be a LONG int; balks at empty string.

---

### Update

The function below line 140 in DB_Driver is where the dbcollat and charset are set. Those will hit real_escape in the driver, and cause the escape_error if not correct.

Try

```
$db['default']['dbcollat']='';
```

Or, check that the encoding your db is set for what you have in your db config. i.e. if your db charset is latin1 and you are using utf-8, the conn_id will be wrong and mysqli_escape will balk.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. :( I have no idea what to try next.

Comment: Don't know man... I went through all the steps on a fresh local install, though not on windows. I went through the steps, and was getting the same `can't find db` error, and the param 6 error in CI logs; once port was added to config it worked. Check: location/permissions of ca_cert file (I left that NULL here; if I set to wrong path, I get an `unable to connect with settings` error, not unable to find db). Finally (and maybe most importantly), if you happen to be using XAMPP, SSL is tricky: http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=42946#p169097

Comment: Thanks for trying. :) I tried the above but no luck unfortunately. I can't believe `codeigniter` is having trouble with this. I'm going to give `doctrine` + codeigniter a try.

Comment: Are you seeing `log_message('error', 'Unable to select database: '.$this->database);` in the logs? Or just the escape errors?

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the log because I haven't turned on error logging. But if I did I'm sure that line will present. Do you think it won't appear?

Comment: I ask because it would help narrow down exactly where the problem is. `$this->db_select()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`; something after that is what is triggering the escape errors.... Updated my answer.

Comment: Oh God, this is embarrassing! I set logging to `4` and I found this error: `streams.crypto this stream does not support SSL/crypto` which basically means I needed to do just `extension=php_openssl.dll`. Fail. Thanks for telling me to check the logs stormdrain! It's also **very** important to set `$db['default']['port'] = 3306;` otherwise it won't work and you'll get the same error.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it! wat is an dll? ;)

Answer (score 1):

if used Codeigniter 3.* config db file is different:

```
$db['default']['encrypt']['ssl_set'] = true;
$db['default']['encrypt']['ssl_key'] = NULL;
$db['default']['encrypt']['ssl_cert'] = NULL;
$db['default']['encrypt']['ssl_ca'] = realpath('./application/third_party/sert/CA.pem');
$db['default']['encrypt']['ssl_capath'] = NULL;
$db['default']['encrypt']['ssl_cipher'] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter 4, you have to update the value of `encrypt` in the `$default` variable on the `app/Config/Database.php` file. Like this

```
'encrypt'  => [
  'ssl_key' => NULL,
  'ssl_cert' => NULL,
  'ssl_verify' => FALSE,
  'ssl_ca' => '',
  'ssl_capath' => NULL,
  'ssl_cipher' => NULL
]
```

And then you can use the `.env` file to change some of the values if you want. Like this

```
database.default.encrypt.ssl_verify = true
database.default.encrypt.ssl_ca = './application/third_party/sert/CA.pem'
```

Note: any value that needs to be updated in the `.env` file must be set in the `app/Config/Database.php` file. You can just set it as an empty string, `false` or `NULL`.